# atoi() makes the program crash

Tags: c, crash, atoi

I have a strange problem with atoi():
I have a string  (let's say str) which is something like "aaaa 1111\0" (I printed and checked - it's really it).
I tried to perform atoi on str+5, and the program just crashed. I added a log one line before and after, and I can see the one before, but nothing after it. So the problem is in this line.
I also printed str+5, the result is as expected, so there's nothing wrong with the string either.

I then tried to create a char[] array of size 5, copied the 4 numbers and added null terminated at the end.
It still crashes...

Adding code:

```
int int_pin;
char buff[MAX_LEN + PIN_LEN + 1];  //MAX_LEN = 5, PIN_LEN = 4
//reading size of MAX_LEN + PIN_LEN from file to buff...
buff[MAX_LEN + PIN_LEN] = '\0';
int_pin = atoi(buff+MAX_LEN);    //crashes
```

Edit: I also tried the simplest code:
    `char a[] = "1234";` 
    `int_pin = atoi(a);`

And it still crashes.
Do you have any idea why a simple atoi() call makes my program to crash?

Comment: *"Code speaks louder than words"* You need to post a code example demonstrating the problem rather than describing the problem in words.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `#include <stdlib.h>` to include atoi function?

I tried this and it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    char string[] = "aaaa 1111";
    int int_pin = atoi(string+5);
    printf("%d", int_pin); /* returns 1111 as intended */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Are you getting any warnings if you compile with `-Wall`?

Comment: yes - do post more code since what you posted as code works as expected.

Comment: Thank you guys. I just tried the simplest thing: `char a[] = "1234"; int_pin = atoi(a);` and it still crashes! I think there's something wrong with my machine...

Comment: What machine/ide/compiler do you use?

Comment: gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)